# Ao capturar tela ocorre o erro: raised exception class EOutOfResources with message

Tags: delphi

Estou utilizando Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010 Delphi.

Estava fazendo testes para capturar a as imagens da tela de outros computadores via sockets. Então me deparei com um erro ao capturar a tela e transformar para JPG (ou até mesmo gravar como padrão BMP), após uns 10 segundos - executando um `TTimer` com intervalo de 400 dá-se o erro:

> [nomeProjeto.exe] raised exception class EOutOfResources with message
>   'Espaço insuficiente de armazenamento para processar este comando.'.

Ao verem o código do evento do Timer, verão que (para testes) estou apenas executando a `function CapturaTelaJpg` sem salvá-la em nada (mas ele salva perfeitamente), e mesmo assim o erro ocorre após os 10 segundos.

```
function CapturaTelaJpg: TJpegImage;
var
  dc : hdc;
  cv : TCanvas;
  aux : TBitmap;
begin

  Result := TJPEGImage.Create;

  aux := TBitmap.Create;
  aux.Height := Screen.Height;
  aux.Width := Screen.Width;

  dc := GetDC(0);
  cv := TCanvas.Create;
  cv.Handle := dc;

  //--Define o tamanho da imagem
  aux.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0,0,Screen.Width,Screen.Height),cv,
  Rect(0,0,Screen.Width,Screen.Height));
  cv.Free;
  cv := nil;
  ReleaseDC(0,dc);

  //-- Compacta o BMP para JPEG
  Result.Assign(aux);
  aux.Free;
  aux := nil;
  Result.Compress;

end;
```

`Timer1` com intervalo 400

```
procedure TfrmMonitorando.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

  CapturaTelaJpg; // 10s depois, ocorre o erro colocando ou não numa variável

end;
```

Comment: Vamos por parte, 1º realize o procedimento no seu próprio PC, se o erro ocorrer não tem nada relacionado com a rede, se não ocorrer o erro seu problema é no tamanho de memória usado pelo lado cliente! 2º timer com interval 400 ??????????? ctz disso 400 é menos que meio segundo, ou seja seu timer esta a cada segundo chamando a mesma função 2 vezes.

Comment: Não importa o interval o erro continua ocorrendo, só demora um pouco mais para aparecer. E o teste realizado não foi feito na na rede, está em meu pc. Por algum motivo a function não é descarregada da memória. Mesmo que eu coloque interval := 5000, o erro aparece assim mesmo. É que na verdade, cada vez que ele executa a function, ele cria um TJpegImage, certo? Então eu teria que tirar da memória esse objeto retornado. Não sou muito experiente. Queria saber como tirar da memória este retorno.

Comment: Coloca um BreakPoint na função e depura ela e informe onde esta o erro! Vai apertando F8 e vendo ate onde ela consegue ir!

Comment: Não não. você não entendeu. A function funciona perfeitamente. o que está acontecendo é que ela está empilhando memória.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, crie um novo projeto, coloque usa função e declare nas uses `JPEG`.

Agora adicione um componente `TImage`, um componente `TTimer` com `Interval` 400.

No  componente `TTimer` aplique a chamada da função mas dessa forma:

```
procedure frmTeste.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Picture.Assign(CapturaTelaJpg);
end;
```

Rodou perfeitamente sem erros por mais de 5 minutos!

O Problema é que você chamou a função e não usou o conteúdo dela!

> Nota, não modifiquei nada, apenas copiei sua função e colei!
>   A única mudança foi na chamada!

**Edit:**

Vamos lá, no inicio de sua função adicione:

```
//Aqui adicionamos uma tentativa de eliminar resto de memória!
  if Result <> nil then
    Result := Nil;
```

Comente ou remova a linha `Result.Compress;`

PS: Não mude nada além disso em sua função! Restante esta funcionando Bem!

Comment: Enquanto a aplicação roda, você pode mover o formulário e observar a função funcionando e atualizando o TImage em tempo real!

Comment: Um adicional, pedi para criar um novo projeto pois, com o projeto do ZERO aqui não deu erro, se der erro você deve procurar no projeto se existe algo a mais chamando a função!

Comment: Amigo, fiz como você falou. Não está dando erro, mas é porque o projeto está bem leve agora. Veja em seu gerenciador de tarefas o consumo de memória dele subindo infinitamente.

Comment: Negativo, aqui o consumo ficou paralisado em 60mb, é compreensível os 60mb devido minha tela ser gigante e estar usando BMP!

Comment: e já testou com o jpeg? aqui o consumo fica subindo não importa o intervalo
ele empilha a memória na linha "Result.Compress" (na vdd qnd a function traz o retorno)

Comment: Editei a resposta, baixou meu consumo de memória, porem o elevado consumo pode ser a versão do Delphi ou a arquitetura do processador (meu e seu)

Comment: Ok funcionou (mas o result := nil n faz diferença). mas eu preciso comprimir a imagem para mandar mais rápido pela rede. Ou há outra forma mais "usual"?

Comment: JPEG já é comprimida, não conheço outro método! O result := nil é funcional caso sua função engasgar! é um Controle!

Comment: Ah sim sim. entendi. obg. eu fiz doutro jeito aqui e tmbm funcionou. fiz como procedure e coloquei uma jpg por parâmetro e depois dei um .free nele e foi também. obrigado pelo esclarecimento